# Asymptote vertical / horizontal

Tags: limits, functions, graphing-functions

I am finding Horizontal and vertical asymptotes of function 
$$x^{-3}e^{\frac{x^3}{3}}$$

and i have litte problem with horizontal, because 
$$y =kx +q$$
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac{f(x)}{x}} = k \in R$$
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}{f(x)-kx} = q \in R $$
But first limit equals infinity, what does it mean? Because when i draw graph in WolframAlpha i see thete horizonal asymptote = 0. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function have not asymptote when $x \to +\infty$. The only asymptote is $y=0$ when $x \to -\infty$.

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -\infty} x^{-3}e^{\frac{x^3}{3}} = \lim_{x \to -\infty} x^{-3} \times \lim_{x \to -\infty} e^{\frac{x^3}{3}}=0 \times 0 =0$.

The formula $\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac{f(x)}{x}} = k \in R$ is good also for $k=0$ but if directly $\lim_{x \to \infty}{f(x)} =0$ this is sufficient to conclude that $y=0$ is asymptote in $+\infty$.